# react: преобразовать текст в html код

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

подскажите, как можно преобразовать текст внутри которого также указываются html теги в html код

если более точно, то у меня есть строка, которая содержит html код:

```
this.state = {
    text: 'test <b>BOLD</b> test2 <span class = "c01">Red text</span>'
};
```

и мне необходимо, чтоб этот текст был отображён как html код:

```
    render() {       
        return (
<div>{this.state.text}</div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser как вариант использовать библиотеку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
render() {       
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.text }} />
  );
}
```

Comment: жаль только что это именно `dangerously`